# Render Attribute for p:treeNode is not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces v5.3. when using the render attribute for `p:treeNode` as shown below,

```
 <p:treeNode type="data" icon="fa fa-cloud" rendered="#{node.state == 'live'}">
     <h:outputText value=" #{node.name}" title="#{node.state}" style="white-space: normal;float: left;"/>
</p:treeNode>
```

Property not found exception is thrown,

```
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'state' not found on type java.lang.String
```

However if I remove the rendered attribute alone it works fine, it seems like my object is considered as java.lang.String by EL, any idea ???

Comment: 'Not working' is not the best thing to put in a title. If I see a title like that, my first impression is that the poster spend to little time writing a good question since 'not working' is a statement from an end-user, not a developer. Since And if you post about something not working, post a [mcve]. Both things, a good title and an mcve are mentioned in [ask]. Can you improve your question?

Comment: what is `node` (where do you define it, which type)? Also, use `eq` for comparison instead of `==`

Comment: @jp-jee: If OP creates a [mcve] all  that will become visible (including other probably relevant things that are not mentioned/requested)... So it is always better to just ask for a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

There is no any node.state in TreeNode(see here https://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/6.0/org/primefaces/model/TreeNode.html)

Use something else like: node.selectable, node.type, node.contains("something")

Comment: You seem to thing that the 'node' var contains a TreeNode object. According to the docs, it does not. It contains the **data** from the TreeNode (page 544 of the 6.1 docs: _Name of the request-scoped variable that'll be used to refer each treenode **date**)
to refer each treenode data._)

Comment: I'm used to deal with node as a String. Look at this:
<h:outputText value="#{node.substring(0, node.indexOf('|'))}"/>

Comment: Yes, but OP is most likely not (nor am I)... You **can** put 'complex' objects in the data field.